# Why Java can run the code without cost of time?

Tags: java, c++

I have written a little program to generate the unique ID. And print out the cost of time. Here is the code:

```java
public class JavaSF_OLD {

    static int randomNumberShiftBits = 12;
    static int randomNumberMask = (1 << randomNumberShiftBits) - 1;
    static int machineNumberShiftBits = 5;
    static int machineNumberMask = (1 << machineNumberShiftBits) - 1;
    static int dataCenterNumberShiftBits = 5;
    static int dataCenterNumberMask = (1 << dataCenterNumberShiftBits) - 1;
    static int dateTimeShiftBits = 41;
    static long dateTimeMask = (1L << dateTimeShiftBits)-1;

    static int snowFlakeId = 0;
    static long lastTimeStamp = 0;
    static int DataCenterID = 1;
    static int MachineID = 1;

    public static long get() {
//        var current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var current = 164635438;
        if (current != lastTimeStamp) {
            snowFlakeId = 0;
            lastTimeStamp=current;
        }else{
            snowFlakeId++;
        }

        long id = 0;

        id |= current&dateTimeMask;

        id <<= dataCenterNumberShiftBits;
        id |= DataCenterID&dataCenterNumberMask;

        id <<= machineNumberShiftBits;
        id |= MachineID&machineNumberMask;

        id <<= randomNumberShiftBits;
        id |= snowFlakeId & randomNumberMask;

        return id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long result  = 0;
        for (int out = 0; out < 10; out++) {
            var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                result = get();
            }
            var end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end - start);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The result seems to be a little wierd.

```
53
690531076282879
5
690531076281343
0
690531076283903
0
690531076282367
0
690531076280831
0
690531076283391
0
690531076281855
0
690531076284415
0
690531076282879
0
690531076281343
```

It use 0 millionsecond to get the right result, while the C++ version needs 230 millionseconds to get one result. When I change the number of the inner loop from 1000000000 to 1e9, which is of type double, it takes more than one second to get per result. How could this be?

I change the number of loop of C++ version and there is no change at all. So I guess Java optimizes the loop and omit the first 999999999 loops. And how could Java optimize it actually and run it at no cost but get the correct result? And how to optimize C++ version of the same code to skip the useless loop? I use -O3 flag but it seems not working.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

static const unsigned int randomNumberShiftBits = 12;
static const unsigned int randomNumberMask = (1u << randomNumberShiftBits) - 1;
static const unsigned int machineNumberShiftBits = 5;
static const unsigned int machineNumberMask = (1u << machineNumberShiftBits) - 1;
static const unsigned int dataCenterNumberShiftBits = 5;
static const unsigned int dataCenterNumberMask = (1u << dataCenterNumberShiftBits)-1;
static const unsigned int dateTimeShiftBits = 41;
static const unsigned long long dateTimeMask = (1ull << dateTimeShiftBits) - 1;

static uint32_t snowFlakeId = 0;
static unsigned long long lastTimeStamp = 0;
static unsigned int DataCenterID=1;
static unsigned int MachineID=1;


std::int64_t get() {
//    auto current = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    auto current = 164635438;
    if (current != lastTimeStamp) {
        snowFlakeId = 0;
        lastTimeStamp = current;
    }else{
        snowFlakeId++;
    }
    unsigned long long id = 0;
    // Datetime part
    id |= static_cast<unsigned long long>(static_cast<unsigned long long>(current) & dateTimeMask);

    // DataCenter Part
    id <<= dataCenterNumberShiftBits;
    id |= static_cast<uint>(static_cast<uint>(DataCenterID)&dataCenterNumberMask);

    // Machine Part
    id <<= machineNumberShiftBits;
    id |= static_cast<uint>(static_cast<uint>(MachineID)&machineNumberMask);

    // Random Number Part
    id <<= randomNumberShiftBits;
    id |= static_cast<uint>(snowFlakeId&randomNumberMask);

    return id;
}

int main() {
    for (int out = 0; out < 10; out++) {
        uint64_t result = 0;
        auto start = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            result = get();
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        std::cout << (end - start) << std::endl;
        std::cout<<result<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the C++ version and the result of it:

```
1419
690531076282879
1385
690531076281343
1388
690531076283903
1457
690531076282367
1407
690531076280831
1402
690531076283391
1441
690531076281855
1389
690531076284415
1395
690531076282879
1360
690531076281343
```

As for measuring the time, it's just the code in the main function. I know the algorithm is wrong and I am just curious why Java could do that and how to make C++ skip the loop as well.

Comment: Please show the c++ version as well, and describe clearly how you're measuring timings.

Comment: Also, this calculation looks like it never changes. The JVM might be smart enough to realize that.

Comment: Did you enable full optimization in the c++ code?

Comment: Both the Java and C++ version are wrong in the unique part: from `690531076282879` it starts to repeat itself. Only the first 8 numbers are 'unique' (well I can't say they are if every time you run the program it outputs the same).

Comment: You can add `-XX:+PrintCompilation -Xbatch -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly` flags to `java` if you're **really** interested in knowing what the JVM is doing.

Comment: @Fullslack.dev yeah I know the ID will repeat. I use unchanged datetime just for short run time, because getting the current datetime costs too much and I want to remove the effect of the difference of the getting time function.

Comment: Another contributing factor can be a combination of timer resolution and simple, optimized code that might complete before the value returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()` increases.

Comment: @drescherjm Yeah I use -O3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're operating under a ton of misconceptions.

### System.currentTimeMillis() as ID is a bad idea

This is a very bad idea. your code is *clearly* designed to treat System.currentTimeMillis (`cTM`) as a strictly increasing sequence. For example, if the current time is 10000, and I ask for an id, I get `10000:0`. If I ask again, I'd get `10000:1`. If time then becomes 10001, I'd get `10001:0`, and if time then warps back to 10000, I'd get `10000:0` again, violating the intent of generating unique numbers.

But here is the thing: **`cTM` has absolutely no guarantee that it is strictly increasing.**

cTM reflects the system clock. On some backward systems, the system clock represents local time and not UTC. Java is supposed to 'fix' that, but getting time warped back 3600000 milliseconds (one hour's worth) is known to happen during daylight savings adjustments. More generally, most computers get the time from some network source and will adjust time by a few seconds (which is THOUSANDS of milliseconds easily) all the time. There are solutions if you must have unique IDs and system time is the only possible provider but entire PhD research papers have been written about how to do it (it's called 'smearing', and your computer is probably not doing it, and the JVM just reports  back what the OS is telling it, so it won't smear either).

System.nanoTime() is more or less guaranteed to increase, but it loops back around every 36 days or so. If you want unique IDs, use the right tool: UUIDs. Generating unique IDs is harder than you think, and a solved problem. Use the existing solution.

### Timing performance with cTM is a bad idea

That's wrong too. Java works very roughly as follows:

Run all code very slowly and stupidly, and keep track of all sorts of completely irrelevant information, such as 'for this if branch, how often does the expression resolve to 'true' vs. 'false'', or 'how often is this method called'. Gathering these stats makes it even more inefficient. The JVM is now extremely inefficient. But this is good, you'll see in a moment. Contrast to C code where `gcc` or whatever compiler you use will analyse the heck out of your source code and make the most optimized machinecode that it can, but that's where it ends: No bookkeeping. It's optimized code right from the compile stop. Vs. java; `javac` is very simple and quite stupid, it does almost no optimization. It's `java` itself, at runtime, that does.

Then, from time to time, do an analysis: Which of alllll the methods in the system, is taking up the most CPU time? Then, take a moment and all those seemingly useless stats to generate one heck of an amazing fine-tuned optimized machine-coded version of this method. It can and often will outperform handwritten code; after all, java has the benefit of knowing the behaviours in real time, for this actual workload, whereas something like C-written code can't know that. Java even gets to generate code with assumptions built in, because java can 'invalidate' this optimized variant if one of the assumptions fails later on.

The upshot is that, again, oversimplifying  by a lot, the general performance characteristic of any given method is that it takes X time per run for a while (X being, say, 1000), then one call that takes waaaay longer as the system does the analysis (say, 10000000), and then all further invokes takes Y time, where Y is much, much less than X (say, 10).

The # of cycles at 1000, and that one blip as it recompiled, are 'constant', and then the actual time of 10 is for all further cycles. As more and more cycles are applied (and as we only optimize often-called methods, the 10 cycles dwarf the others), the 10 is the only important number for performance purposes.

**But it does mean you need to wait until that happened before you measure performance**, and that is not easy at all. You also get other 'noise'. Maybe your thread gets pre-empted by winamp because it needs to unpack some more of that MP3 file, causing a huge blip on your timing arbitrarily.

The answer is [`JMH`](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). Yet again, some problem: The job at hand (timing a method call) is orders of magnitude more complicated than you think it is, but it is a solved problem, so use the existing solutions.

### Some guesstimates about your observed performance

If you make that a double, then you have to add 1 to a double, which can be orders of magnitude slower, as is double comparisons. Eventually your method will just run forever (if you go to large numbers, x+1 is just x, in double land. Think about it: Doubles are 64-bit, so can only represent at most 2^64 different numbers. And yet a double can do, say, 1e308. How can you fit 1e308 pigeons in only 2^64 holes? The answer is: You can't. Not every number between 0 and infinite is representable as a double, and when you try to set something to a number not in that space of 2^64 representables, java silently rounds to the nearest. Eventually the gap between representables exceeds 1.0, and at that point, `i++` fails to make any changes to i. It's not quite at 1e9 (it's I think, at around 2^53), but doing increment counting with doubles is always a bad idea. Go with `long` if you must.

Furthermore, both C and java (but not javac, that hotspot analyser I talked about in the second point) have 'optimizers'. If the optimizer realizes that [A] you don't actually use the result of `get()` anywhere in your code, and [B] the get() method either has no side effects at all, or the side effects can be fully covered by only running a fraction of the total instructions in get(), then **the optimizer is free to just NOT run that method**, or at least run only parts of it, which would cause **wildly** different performance measurements.

JMH solves this too: For example, it FORCES you to return some numeric value in your measurement method, as JMH will mix this number into a value it keeps track of, thus forcing the optimizer to realize it can't just 'optimize' by skipping the entire call!

### cTM is not free

The `System.currentTimeMillis()` is, or can be, quite expensive. C as a language makes almost no promises about anything (it doesn't even promise that an `int` is 32-bit!), but any particular given library impl tends to make extremely specific promises about what a given call does. Java lies in the middle. It means that what java actually ends up executing at the OS level when you run `cTM` may be different, and involve some caches + using the CPU core's own internal clock which is many orders of magnitude faster than 'asking for the system time', whereas the C call farms out the work to the system time every time you call it, because the C code assumes that if you want to optimize and estimate with CPU core updates, that you'd then program that or fetch a library that will. You're (potentially) mostly timing the performance of cTM here and not of your algorithm, and between the C and the java code cTM may have **wildly** different implementations. You're comparing guns to grandmas, in other words.

JMH, as usual, helps you out here, and avoids the issues with cTM. Not that I know of a way to compare JMH results with C results, but at least a JMH timing result is something you can trust a heck of a lot more than handspun deltas between cTM calls.

### cTM is not as stable as you think it is

cTM sucks. The problem is: Clocks are really hard. I know, I know, you can go to the store, buy a 5 cent watch with some cheap crystal in there and it's surprisingly accurate. But the surface of a computer chip is an extremely inhospitable place, with wild temperature swings, electrons flowing all over the place, and a ton of air being moved nearby. Trying to keep a quartz crystal stable in those conditions is tricky. So either the system clock is far away from the CPU but now asking for the system time is incredibly expensive compared to basic instructions (literally hundreds of thousands of cycles, as the electrons make their way, like slow molasses, over cable of many centimeters long, an eternity in computer CPU terms), or it's on board (and they are), and not as stable as you'd like.

CPU cores have internal clocks which can be more stable but are more unbound from reflecting any actual time, and cause serious issues if your code is moved to another core which has a completely different core clock. Java gives you access to this - `System.nanoTime`, and even tries to smooth out the core hop issues, but as is the theme in this answer: Time is way, way harder than you think it is, but fortunately it is a mostly solved problem. Note how nanoTime intentionally returns a meaningless number: It has meaning only in relation to other calls to nanoTime, it doesn't mean anything by itself (whereas cTM means: millis since midnight 1970-1-1 UTC). It's tricky - JMH solved the problem, you should use that.